# How to get rid of macro leftovers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2013, autorun, ribbon

Old macro workbook from Microsoft samples gallery left items on the **ADD-INS** ribbon tab, highlighted by yellow:

[image]

These cannot be deleted or at least I don't know where to find them – see **Customize Ribbon** window open on the screenshot – they are not there.

Items are bound to still functional macros, but I can't find their code. There is nothing in top-left pane (which shows list of VBA modules) in VBA IDE.

I have checked all Addin types in **Excel Options** > **Add-ins**, they are not there.
I have checked **Add-ins** and **COM Add-ins** items on ribbon's **DEVELOPER** tab, these do not contain it.
I have checked **Addin Manager** in VBA IDE, it is empty.
I checked for hidden workbooks in **View** tab (thanks @AlexFrolov) and **Unhide** button is disabled.
The only list I did not check was list of **Automation Servers** due to its length (it can be opened using **Add-ins** window).

**ADD-INS** ribbon tab is missing only in Excel Safe mode but unwanted icons are always present in standard mode.

How can I delete this toolbar labeled "**Custom toolbar**" from **ADD-INS** ribbon tab?

Comment: Sounds like an add-in customized the ribbon UI, which is done via xml. [see info in this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba). Given I've never used this feature of excel, I can't think of how to help. Look up on how to reset the xml that powers the ribbon UI.

Comment: [Here is the MS KB on ribbon xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx), I'd look there to find the default and reactivate it.

Comment: Please check if you have any hidden workbooks (like Personal.xlsb) opened: 
`View` tab -> `Window` group -> `Unhide`.

Comment: @AlexFrolov I didn't even consider the fact that it may be calling from the personal macro workbook. +1

Comment: My best guess is a ribbonui element that has stored itself in the default template.  Open a different template and see if the ribbon is still there.  If not, find the default template file and delete the XML by unzipping the file and searching for it.

Comment: @AlexFrolov – the control is disabled. I have edited the question to make it more complete. Thanks.

Comment: @Raystafarian – let me try this a bit later and then come back with feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customizations disappeared due to unknown reason.
To make sure everything is all right I pressed **Reset** button (also visible on the image in the question above). Now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

@ miroxlav: Still looking for an answer? You could try the following:

- in your highlighted ribbon > right-click on one of the symbols (to make sure you hit the custom toolbar) > within the context-menu choose "Delete custom menu" (wording may be slightly different, am using a German Excel here).

Hope that helps!
Mike